# Post json data as plain text with new line in Django REST API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a python service(web) in which i want to input plain texts with new lines using Django REST API. For example,

**Input:**

3
January
February
June

I want to input this constrains **with new line** in the below django API content form. See below picture,

[image]

I will get the output by some calculation after retrieving the post **input values** in APIView. The Response will be the output as an JSON. For example, **[ "01",  "02", "03" ]**

**My problem** is when i try to post that **input** (texts with new lines). It gives error as below,
[image]

How can i input (plain text with new line) through this python Django REST API and the output will be as a response be an ordered json array.

**Thanks in advance for your guidelines**

Comment: Do you have knowledge about application/json file before? Your content is incorrect, guy!

Comment: Yes, i have knowledge. But i am trying a new things so that i can not getting how to go ahead.
You may see the approach to do in the below image link,
https://ibb.co/cxvhBH7

Comment: Got it, you are wrong. You should build a service that can handle reading a file then order the data in a file and return a response. It's not JSON input, must be FILE type input (plain text)

Comment: Oh no. Thanks for your guide @Vu Phan!
It should be file input through the API and then i should read the texts of that file and calculate results. Then i need to return the results as JSON array.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to send your request body as multi-line text, there are a couple of stuff you need to do.

1. Create a PlainTextParser

> This is needed because DjangoRestFramework by default has JSONParser as its default, that is why you are seeing the error message you are receiving

If you follow this [GuidLine](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#custom-parsers) you will see how to implement it.

```
import codecs

from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework.exceptions import ParseError
from rest_framework.parsers import BaseParser

class PlainTextParser(BaseParser):
    media_type = "text/plain"

    def parse(self, stream, media_type=None, parser_context=None):
        """
        Parses the incoming bytestream as Plain Text and returns the resulting data.
        """
        parser_context = parser_context or {}
        encoding = parser_context.get('encoding', settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET)

        try:
            decoded_stream = codecs.getreader(encoding)(stream)
            text_content = decoded_stream.read()
            return text_content
        except ValueError as exc:
            raise ParseError('Plain text parse error - %s' % str(exc))
```

2. Add that parser to Django Rest Framework configuration

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        'path.to.PlainTextParser' # Replace path.to with you project path to that class
    ],
    ...
}
```

> If you want it to only work on specific Views, you can add it to its `parser_classes`

3. When you do your request in DjangoRestFramwork Browsable API, choose text/plain as your media type, and in your http client put `Content-Type: text/plain`

This should be it, I hope it helps.

Comment: The best answer here @milton

Comment: Thanks @VuPhan , I appreciate your comment

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this parser with media-type=text/plain and it works fine.
@RadwanAbu-Odeh

Comment: Thanks @RadwanAbu-Odeh for your answer. I tried your solution, it worked for plain text. After implementing your solution I faced some issue on my other API's. I got `Unsupported media type ` error. 
To fix the `unsupported media type` issue, I had to add more parser into `DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES`.
These are:
`rest_framework.parsers.FormParser'`,
`rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [raw string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) instead of what you are doing

```
    In [4]: n_s="This is \t Stack over \n flow"

    In [5]: r_s=r"This is  \t Stack over \n flow" 

    In [8]: print(n_s)
    This is      Stack over 
    flow

   In [9]: print(r_s)
   This is  \t Stack over \n flow
```

try posting as triple-quotes r'''..'''

Comment: I have tried as you told to use  triple-quotes r'''..'''. It does not work and shows error.

But the input will not contain any '\n' character. The input is like as plain text with line break.

Comment: can you post the actual json you are dealing?

Comment: "
3
January
February
June
"
Please see the 1st picture in the question. In the comment section, new line not working in inputs.